# Why isn't my background image showing up for my jumbotron?

Tags: html, css

Trying to get a background image for my jumbotron but nothing is working.

I have made sure my CSS comes after Bootstraps CSS and I've also tried changing the path. The image is in the right folder too.

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(pepperonis.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1><strong> My Favorite Foods In The World</strong></h1>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you followed the console? Maybe your code can't find your way to the picture. If the picture path is correct, would you also write the bootstrap version?

Comment: Does pepperonis.jpg need to be in quotes?

Comment: @NicholasPorter quotes would only be needed if there was a empty space in the image path.

Comment: Okay, you also need to put `<meta>` tags in the `<head>`, not in the `<body>`

Comment: @BOZ Picture path is correct, I have tried it several different ways, and I'm not too sure what you're asking about the bootstrap version.

Comment: @NicholasPorter Thanks, just updated that.

Comment: Still no luck with the jumbotron background image though.

Comment: Works for me. Likely it's being trumped with some other css. try this instead {background-image: url(pepperonis.jpeg) !important;

Comment: The thing is i barely have any CSS linked to my HTML so I should be able to spot the issue pretty easily. I tried the !important; trick but no luck either.

Comment: Console actually is saying pepperoni.jpeg cannot be found. What could i be doing wrong? Do i need to type out the full path? Like ("/Desktop/Week 1/Bootstrap/pepperoni.jpeg")

Comment: Where is your image located? What is the exact path?

Are you also in a local environment or in a live server?

Comment: "icloud drive/desktop/week 1/bootstrap/pepperoni.jpeg" is the exact path of my image. And i'm in a local environment.

Answer (score -2):

Ok Jordan I see some crazy stuff going on here. But to answer your question, your background url is not linked to any file, just an image.

```
    .jumbotron {
     background-image:("/images/something.jpeg")
    }
```

This is just an example hope it helps

Comment: I'm fairly new to coding so I apologize for the mess. But i have tried every kind of path I could possibly do. My path to the image is "icloud drive/desktop/week 1/bootstrap/pepperoni.jpeg". And i'm in a local environment. My CSS file is in the bootstrap folder.

Comment: If the file and the image are in the same folder, then this shouldn't  be an issue.